# 8 bitTwo's complement in the simplest way possible please

Tags: twos-complement

I really need help understanding twos complement. I have been set with the task of converting some negative numbers into binary using 8 bit Two's complete but I have literally no idea what I have to do. Can someone help, if someone could explain it in the simplest way that would be really helpful. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is :
from right to left start copying all digits untill you get a 1, copy it too, then invert all the rest,
so 1111 1011, you start copying the 1, you reached the first one, so next start inverting the rest:
0000 0101 witch is -5.
another example: 1111 1000 -> 0000 1000 that is -8
I hope it helps.
more info: [Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to add 256 to the number.

For example, if you have -42, the two's complement is:

```
256 + -42 = 214
```

214 in binary is 11010110.

You can also do the calculation in binary, then you would subtract 42 from 256:

```
 100000000
-   101010
----------
  11010110
```